# Python script using subprocess to get PID and kill it acts weird when launched from outside its sitting directory

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess

Thank you in advance for the time you'll give to read this question. I am learning Python and I looked up a lot before asking here, please forgive me for the newbie question.

So I created this script in python 3 using subprocess module to search for another python script's PID, while only knowing the beginning of the script's name and terminate it nicely.

Basically I run python clocks on my LCD screen through Raspberry and I2C, and I terminate the script, clear the LCD and turn it off. This "off" script code is provided below.

The issue is that when I run it from the directory it sits in with a:

`python3 off.py`

It works perfectly, getting parsing and terminating the PID, then turning off the LCD display.

Ideally I want to trigger it through telegram-cli because I did it in bash and it worked nicely, I find it to be a nice feature. In python it fails.

So I tested and it appears that when I try to launch it from another directory like this:

`python3 ~/code/off.py`

The grep subprocess returns more than the one PID it returns normally when launched from the script residing directory. For instance (with python3 -v):

```
kill: failed to parse argument: '25977
26044'
```

The second PID number is from a sub process created by the script, I can't seem to find what it is as it terminates when the script ends but fails it initial purpose.

Any help in understanding what is happening here would be really appreciated.
I came so far, as show below, from two ugly lines of bash mixed with a call to an dummy four lines python scripts, so I really feel I am getting close to a proper way of achieving my first real python script.

I tried to decompose the script line by line in the interpreter and could not reproduce the error, everything behave as expected. I only get this double PID result when running the script from an outer location.

Thank you in advance for any helpful insight on how to understand what is happening!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import I2C_LCD_driver
import string

# Defining variables for searched strings and string encoding
searched_process_name = 'lcd_'
cut_grep_out_of_results = 'grep'
result_string_encoding = 'utf-8'
mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()
LCD_NOBACKLIGHT = 0x00
run = True

def kill_script():
    # Listing processes and getting the searched process
    ps_process = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "aux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    grep_process = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-i", searched_process_name], stdin=ps_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # The .stdout.close() lines below allow the previous process to receive a SIGPIPE if the next process exits.
    ps_process.stdout.close()
    # Cleaning the result until only the PID number is returned in a string
    grep_cutout = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-v", cut_grep_out_of_results], stdin=grep_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    grep_process.stdout.close()
    awk = subprocess.Popen(["cut", "-c", "10-14"], stdin=grep_cutout.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    grep_cutout.stdout.close()
    output = awk.communicate()[0]
    clean_output = output.decode(result_string_encoding)
    clean_output_no_new_line = clean_output.rstrip()
    clean_output_no_quote = clean_output_no_new_line.replace("'", '')
    PID = clean_output_no_quote
    # Terminating the LCD script process
    subprocess.Popen(["kill", "-9", PID])

while run:
    kill_script()
    # Cleaning and shutting off LCD screen
    mylcd.lcd_clear()
    mylcd.lcd_device.write_cmd(LCD_NOBACKLIGHT)
    break
```

Comment: Apparently your grep found 2 PID's matching your expression, feeds the pair to kill, which doesn't know what to do with 'it'.  All this ps'ing, grep'ing, cut'ing, and kill'ing from python could be avoided. Python has everything to do that without external processes

Comment: @Roadowl that's it indeed, I can't seem to understand what is the second PID, which is created and terminated within the script actually. Regarding the fact that trying to manage python processes at the system level with a python program makes you sad and uneasy, sorry about that, do you have a better suggestion for a learner who don't want to mix ugly bash shortcuts with Python functions, while actually trying its best to learn it in the process?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason of this weird comportment. An error on my end:
I forgot I called some directories with a name including the characters string I was running grep **-i** against provoking the double result when running the script from outside its directory using its full path.
Turns out the script runs pretty well using subprocess.

So in the end, I renamed the scripts I wanted to terminate with disp_ rather than lcd_ and added shell=False to my subprocesses to make sure there were no risk of unwantedly sending the output to bash while the running the script.